# WebdriverIO get cookies method doesn't work

Tags: cookies, wdio

I'm setting a cookie as it is on WDIO page, and then want to show them in the console:

```
await browser.setCookies([
        {name: 'CTSESSION', value: 'AAAAA33jg$ddsAvV54jg9'}
    ])
const testCookie = await browser.getCookies(['CTSESSION'])
console.log(testCookie);
```

but instead of my cookie I'm getting:

```
[object Object]
```

The same I'm getting when I do

```
const testCookie = await browser.getAllCookies()
console.log(testCookie);
```

then in a response I've got:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Can anyone advice why I don't get values?